# iPad Decimal Picker Control

Tags: iphone, ipad, spinner, picker, nsdecimalnumber

I'm just wondering how I go about making a picker/spinner control for a decimal number input. I have seen it on other iPhone apps where they click a button and a number picker comes up and allows them to move the numbers in the spinner to select the number they require.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well I was thinking there would be a predefined one. PickerView alone does not get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple components in the UIPickerControl. Just assign an array of 0-9 for each component, and compose the number after the user has selected a new number in a single component.